# Three.js: Setting `texture.needsUpdate = true` is very slow

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm working on a Three.js scene in which I'd like to update some textures after some time. I'm finding that updating the textures is very slow, however, and drags FPS to only 1-2 FPS for several seconds (when updating just a single texture).

Is there anything one can do to expedite texture updates? Any insights others can offer on this question would be very appreciated.

To see this behavior, click the window of the example below. This will load the first texture update (another click will trigger the second texture update). If you try to zoom after one of these clicks, you'll find the screen freezes and the FPS will drop terribly. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

```html
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; background: #000; }
  body { margin: 0; overflow: hidden; }
  canvas { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/88/three.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://rawgit.com/YaleDHLab/pix-plot/master/assets/js/trackball-controls.js'></script>
  <script src='https://rawgit.com/mrdoob/stats.js/master/build/stats.min.js'></script>

    <script type='x-shader/x-vertex' id='vertex-shader'>
    precision highp float;

    uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
    uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;

    uniform vec3 cameraPosition;

    attribute vec3 position; // sets the blueprint's vertex positions
    attribute vec3 translation; // x y translation offsets for an instance
    attribute float texIdx; // the texture index to access

    varying float vTexIdx;

    void main() {
      // set point position
      vec3 pos = position + translation;
      vec4 projected = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(pos, 1.0);
      gl_Position = projected;

      // assign the varyings
      vTexIdx = texIdx;

      // use the delta between the point position and camera position to size point
      float xDelta = pow(projected[0] - cameraPosition[0], 2.0);
      float yDelta = pow(projected[1] - cameraPosition[1], 2.0);
      float zDelta = pow(projected[2] - cameraPosition[2], 2.0);
      float delta  = pow(xDelta + yDelta + zDelta, 0.5);
      gl_PointSize = 40000.0 / delta;
    }
    </script>

    <script type='x-shader/x-fragment' id='fragment-shader'>
    precision highp float;

    uniform sampler2D a;
    uniform sampler2D b;

    varying float vTexIdx;

    void main() {
      int textureIndex = int(vTexIdx);
      vec2 uv = vec2(gl_PointCoord.x, gl_PointCoord.y);
      if (textureIndex == 0) {
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(a, uv);
      } else if (textureIndex == 1) {
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(b, uv);
      }
    }
    </script>

  <script>

  /**
  * Generate a scene object with a background color
  **/

  function getScene() {
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xaaaaaa);
    return scene;
  }

  /**
  * Generate the camera to be used in the scene
  **/

  function getCamera() {
    var aspectRatio = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, aspectRatio, 0.1, 100000);
    camera.position.set(0, 1, -6000);
    return camera;
  }

  /**
  * Generate the renderer to be used in the scene
  **/

  function getRenderer() {
    // Create the canvas with a renderer
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
    // Add support for retina displays
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    // Specify the size of the canvas
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    // Add the canvas to the DOM
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    return renderer;
  }

  /**
  * Generate the controls to be used in the scene
  **/

  function getControls(camera, renderer) {
    var controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    controls.zoomSpeed = 0.4;
    controls.panSpeed = 0.4;
    return controls;
  }

  /**
  * Generate the points for the scene
  **/

  function addPoints(scene) {
    var BA = THREE.BufferAttribute;
    var IBA = THREE.InstancedBufferAttribute;
    var geometry  = new THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry();

    // add data for each observation
    var n = 10000; // number of observations
    var rootN = n**(1/2);
    var cellSize = 20;
    var translation = new Float32Array( n * 3 );
    var texIdx = new Float32Array( n );
    var translationIterator = 0;
    var texIterator = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<n*3; i++) {
      var x = Math.random() * n - (n/2);
      var y = Math.random() * n - (n/2);
      translation[translationIterator++] = x;
      translation[translationIterator++] = y;
      translation[translationIterator++] = Math.random() * n - (n/2);
      texIdx[texIterator++] = (x + y) > (n/8) ? 1 : 0;
    }
    var positionAttr = new BA(new Float32Array( [0, 0, 0] ), 3);
    var translationAttr = new IBA(translation, 3, 1);
    var texIdxAttr = new IBA(texIdx, 1, 1);
    positionAttr.dynamic = true;
    translationAttr.dynamic = true;
    texIdxAttr.dynamic = true;
    geometry.addAttribute('position', positionAttr);
    geometry.addAttribute('translation', translationAttr);
    geometry.addAttribute('texIdx', texIdxAttr);

    var canvases = [
      getElem('canvas', { width: 16384, height: 16384, }),
      getElem('canvas', { width: 16384, height: 16384, }),
    ]

    var textures = [
      getTexture( canvases[0] ),
      getTexture( canvases[1] ),
    ];

    var material = new THREE.RawShaderMaterial({
      uniforms: {
        a: {
          type: 't',
          value: textures[0],
        },
        b: {
          type: 't',
          value: textures[1],
        }
      },
      vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertex-shader').textContent,
      fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragment-shader').textContent,
    });
    var mesh = new THREE.Points(geometry, material);
    mesh.frustumCulled = false; // prevent the mesh from being clipped on drag
    scene.add(mesh);

    // on the first window click, paint red points
    // on the second window click, paint blue points
    var clicks = 0;
    window.addEventListener('click', function() {
      if (clicks == 0 || clicks == 1) {
        var canvas = canvases[clicks];
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.fillStyle = clicks == 0 ? 'red' : 'blue';
        ctx.rect(0, 0, 16384, 16384);
        ctx.fill();
        textures[clicks].needsUpdate = true;
        clicks++;
      }
    })
  }

  function getTexture(canvas) {
    var tex = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
    tex.needsUpdate = true;
    tex.flipY = false;
    return tex;
  }

  /**
  * Create an element
  **/

  function getElem(tag, obj) {
    var obj = obj || {};
    var elem = document.createElement(tag);
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(attr) {
      elem[attr] = obj[attr];
    })
    return elem;
  }

  /**
  * Add stats
  **/

  function getStats() {
    var stats = new Stats();
    stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
    stats.domElement.style.top = '65px';
    stats.domElement.style.right = '5px';
    stats.domElement.style.left = 'initial';
    document.body.appendChild(stats.domElement);
    return stats;
  }


  /**
  * Render!
  **/

  function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    controls.update();
    stats.update();
  };

  /**
  * Main
  **/

  var stats = getStats();
  var scene = getScene();
  var camera = getCamera();
  var renderer = getRenderer();
  var controls = getControls(camera, renderer);
  addPoints(scene);
  render();

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your canvases are 16384 by 16384. That's basically insanely large.

For RGBA format, that is 1073741824 bytes..  a *gigabyte* of texture data that is getting sent to your GPU from the CPU when you set that texture.needsUpdate = true

You will definitely notice this getting uploaded to the card.

If your use case absolutely requires textures that large.. then you may need to consider doing incremental updates via gl.texSubImage2D, or using a bunch of smaller textures and only updating one of the per frame, or only updating those textures at the start of your app, and not thereafter.

For reference, there are very few cases i've seen where textures > 4k per side are needed.

And that is about 1/16th the size of your textures.

This has nothing to do with three.js btw. It's a fundamental characteristic of GPU/CPU interaction. Uploads and state changes are slow and have to be carefully orchestrated and monitored.

Comment: Well that's embarrassing. I noticed this behavior on a larger and more complicated scene with textures set to `gl.MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE`, and saw no performance increase when I shrank my canvas, but I was not actually shrinking the canvas. Thanks for the `gl.texSubImage2D` reference though. For the record, do you know of studies of performance with fewer huge textures (I'm painting ~1M images) vs more smaller textures? I assumed and quickly tested that fewer tex conditionals in the frag shader would lead to better performance, but I haven't been comprehensive. Either way, thanks for this!

Comment: Actually I apologize for the tone of my answer.. it was a bit condescending. And generally you're correct in the instinct about shader conditionals and also texture binding taking time. There are rendering architectures that work somewhat like you're what you're moving toward.. for instance Carmacks MegaTexture stuff.

Comment: but those schemes work by primarily only doing small texture updates with subImage2d or similar analogs.

One tricky part about using large texture atlasses, is it makes tiling textures on models more complicated. You also can wind up with problems with filtering along the edge of your individual texture swatches, necessitating expanding the border pixels of your swatches to create additional edge data for the filtering to grab.

Comment: Somebody help -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64249319/three-canvastexture-needsupdate-no-helps