# THREE.CanvasTexture needsUpdate no helps

Tags: opencv, canvas, three.js, textures

- I have video tag and he plays simple video. [works]
- I have canvas2d with playing same video [works]
- opencvjs video processing (canvas is output , video is input)- also works
- I have three.js with plane mesh

```js
          texture = new THREE.CanvasTexture(this.$refs.testcanvas)
          texture.needsUpdate = true;
          materialLocal = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture })
          materialLocal.needsUpdate = true;
          materialLocal.map.needsUpdate = true;
          this.mainVideoMesh.material = materialLocal
          this.mainVideoMesh.material.needsUpdate = true;
```

No hepls .  I got just first image screen texture and than stops updating.

In runtime i found ->

```js
  this.scene.children[2].material.map.needsUpdate: undefined
```

Strange situation any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

When using a video as a data source for a texture, the idea is to use the [THREE.VideoTexture](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/textures/VideoTexture) class. This type of texture will automatically manage its `needsUpdate` flag in order to ensure new frames are correctly displayed on your plane mesh.

Using `THREE.VideoTexture` requires that you use the video element as an argument, not the canvas.

Comment: It is ok but i use `video` for opencvjs and output (opencvjs) is `canvas` then i use effected canvas surface data for my my texture (not video) ...

Comment: Something force `this.scene.children[2].material.map.needsUpdate: undefined`  to be undefined.

Comment: `Texture.needsUpdate` is only a setter. There is no getter implemented and hence you always get `undefined`: https://jsfiddle.net/yt5p8z6w/